# AS3 how can I stop rotation from looping?

Tags: loops, actionscript-3, rotation

Seen from above, my character movieclip moves horizontally and vertically.
In starting position the characters nose is facing the top of the screen so when left key is pressed it should rotate 90 degrees to the left and face left + continue the movement facing left.

Because I use a movement function + the rotation it now kind off loops the 90 degree rotation and swirls around in circles to the left. 
I understand why this is happening, but my question to you is;

How can I make it rotate the degree angle only once, and continue the movement facing that direction?

```
var leftArrow:Boolean;
var speed:Number = 4;
var charRadius:Number = 10;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyReleased);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, everyFrame);

function keyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
        leftArrow = true;
    }

}

function keyReleased(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
        leftArrow = false;
    }
}

function everyFrame(event:Event):void {
    var mazehit:Boolean = false;
    if (leftArrow) {

        for(var i:int = 0; i < speed; i++) {
            if(bounds.hitTestPoint(char.x - charRadius - i, char.y, true)) {



                mazehit = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!mazehit) {

            char.x -= speed;
            char.rotation -= 90;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to set the character state variables when the key is pressed and then use that state to animate the character.

For example, set the rotation and x and y velocity when the key is pressed, then use those values to update the characters x and y and rotation on the frame event.

```
var leftArrow:Boolean;
var rightArrow:Boolean;
var speed:Number = 4;
var vx:Number = 0;
var vy:Number = 0;
var heading:Number = 0;
var charRadius:Number = 10;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyReleased);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, everyFrame);

function keyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
        vx = -speed;
        vy = 0;
        heading = 90;
        leftArrow = true;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
        vx = speed;
        vy = 0;
        heading = -90;
        rightArrow = true;
    }


}

function keyReleased(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
        leftArrow = false;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
        rightArrow = false;
    }
}

function everyFrame(event:Event):void {
    var mazehit:Boolean = false;
    if (leftArrow || rightArrow) {

        for(var i:int = 0; i < speed; i++) {
            if(bounds.hitTestPoint(char.x - charRadius - i, char.y, true)) {
                mazehit = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!mazehit) {

            char.x += vx;
            char.y += vy;
            char.rotation = heading;

        }
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, however the registration point is centered, when I press left/right/left the movieclip isn't staying on the same .x, any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: That may have to do with an error I made in the 'keyReleased' method - I had 'leftArrow = false' for both conditions. I have corrected it and it should work now.

Comment: I think it has to do with rotation, your code is exaclty what I asked for, I just need the movieclip to face the directions of the arrowkeys and i'm starting to think rotation might not be the right way. Thank you for your time

Comment: No problem - I hope you find a solution - and feel free to post more questions ;)